# How do I override the email template for django postman?

Tags: django, libraries, messaging

I am trying to override the default email for django-postman's notification system. In the [docs](http://django-postman.readthedocs.org/en/latest/notification.html), it says

> Default templates are provided with the application. Same as for the
>   views, you can override them, and design yours.

However in the code they are used directly from the `postman` folder, e.g. `'postman/email_user_subject.txt'`.

How do I override the templates for email notification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your project's templates directory, create a folder named `postman` and place your templates there. They must be the same name as what you're overriding. Whatever you have in there will override the default. Django looks first in your custom templates folder before defaulting to the app's templates.

Comment: thank you! It worked, but I had a more complex structure so I wasn't sure about where the general templates folder was.